# Loop in Python script, Only get last results

Tags: python, loops

Why do I only get the stats from the last player in PLAYER_NAME?

I would like to get the stats from all the players in PLAYER_NAME.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

PLAYER_NAME = ["andy-murray/mc10", "rafael-nadal/n409"]
URL_PATTERN = 'http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/players/{}/player-stats?year=0&surfaceType=clay'
for item in zip (PLAYER_NAME):
    url = URL_PATTERN.format(item)

    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'mega-table-wrapper'})

    list_of_rows = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        list_of_cells = []
        for cell in row.findAll('td'):
            text = (cell.text.encode("utf-8").strip())
            list_of_cells.append(text)
        list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)


outfile = open("./tennis.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Name", "Stat"])
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Comment: You're recreating `list_of_rows` in every iteration over `PLAYER_NAME`.

Comment: And how do I fix this?

Comment: move the list_of_rows definition outside of the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're recreating `list_of_rows` every time. To fix that, you have to move it outside the for loop, and instead of appending to it, and turning it into a list of lists, extend it.

On a side note, you have a few other issues with your code:

- `zip` is redundant, and it actually ends up converting your names into tuples, which will cause incorrect formatting, you just want to iterate over `PLAYER_NAME`, and while you're at it, maybe rename that to `PLAYER_NAMES` (since it's a list of names)
- When trying to format the string you just have empty braces, you need a number in there to specify the position of the argument in `format` - in this case `{0}`.

```
PLAYER_NAMES = ["andy-murray/mc10", "rafael-nadal/n409"]
URL_PATTERN = 'http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/players/{0}/player-stats?year=0&surfaceType=clay'
list_of_rows = []
for item in PLAYER_NAMES:
    url = URL_PATTERN.format(item)

    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'mega-table-wrapper'})

    # for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    #     list_of_cells = []
    #     for cell in row.findAll('td'):
    #         text = (cell.text.encode("utf-8").strip())
    #         list_of_cells.append(text)
    #     list_of_rows.extend(list_of_cells) # Change to extend here

    # Incidentally, the for loop above could also be written as:
    list_of_rows += [
        [cell.text.encode("utf-8").strip() for cell in row.findAll('td')]
        for row in table.findAll('tr')
    ]
```

Comment: Thak you all for the feedback and advice.